# How to initialize AWS XRay in Lambda C# project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have a c# lambda project and would like to now set up the project for AWS XRay.

My project contains a startup class and within ConfigureServices, Ive added

```
    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IConfigurationRoot root)
    {
        AWSXRayRecorder.InitializeInstance(root);
....
    }
```

Unfortunately, since this is a lambda project, there is no

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

What other code changes to Startup.cs need to be made in order to get the XRay working?

Comment: Official [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-tracing.html) shows how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing `Configure` method in `Startup` file, you may try configure `app.UseXRay()` in `CreateHostBuilder()` in `Program` file.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseXRay("SampleApp")
                });
            });
        });
```

Please note, the [order](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/tree/master#aspnet-core-framework-net-core--nuget) of `AWSXRayMiddleware` in the HTTP request pipeline matters, so you may need to make sure you've configured the pipeline properly.